# Vue Cli без SPA

Tags: vue.js

Встала задача поработать с Vue не как со SPA. Есть вариант, конечно, подключать его через CDN. Но хотелось бы использовать все-таки компонентный подход, а не просто на каждой странице писать огромную логику.
Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты такой реализации? Или если не SPA - то мучайся через обычное подключение как jQuery?

Comment: Попробуйте вот отсюда почитать: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1639 и доку где-то отсюда Build the app in multi-page mode